# How does this code end end up pulling all dependencies for clojure boot?

Tags: clojure

If you want to pull all dependencies for a [boot](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot) Clojure project, it turns out you can add either of the following task to your `build.boot` file.

```
(deftask deps [])
```

or

```
(deftask deps [] (repl :server true))
```

The later also pulls the repl dependencies as mentioned [here](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Boot-for-Leiningen-Users#repl-dependencies).

I cannot figure out why this works though.

Why does creating empty body task cause the task to pull all dependencies? How is it that `(deftask z [] (comp (a) (b) (c))` will only pull the dependencies for `a b c`, but `(deftask z [])` will somehow pull **all** the dependencies for task defined in `build.boot`? Is it a magic sort of thing? If so, why not just include `deps` as a default boot task?

Answer (score 0):

You've already linked the answer.

[Repl Depencencies](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Boot-for-Leiningen-Users#repl-dependencies)

> The repl task is different from most other tasks because the nREPL
> server can't be run in a pod (because you want to have a REPL in the
> project context, not a fresh pod context). So the repl task calls
> set-env! itself to add its nREPL dependencies at runtime when it is
> actually used, and the project has no nREPL dependencies when the repl
> task isn't used.
>
> This means that the method described above will not fetch dependencies
> needed to start the REPL. This could be an issue when building Docker
> images, for example. The solution is to do something like this:
>
> (deftask deps [] (repl :server true))

If you explicitly tell boot that you want to use nREPL it downloads all the required dependencies. The linked section also describes how this is done.

> So the repl task calls set-env! itself to add its nREPL dependencies at runtime when it is actually used,

And that happens independent from your dependencies because your application may not have any additional dependencies.